# PHP exec() works in command line but not when executed via browser

Tags: php, apache, server, after-effects

I have the following line in a php file called batchrender.php:

```
exec('/Applications/Adobe\ After\ Effects\ CC\ 2014/aerender -project /Users/abc/Sites/AETEST1.aep -comp "Komp1" -output /Users/abc/Sites/xyz.mov');
```

When I call this file via web browser it should render a movie with the aerender unix command.

The output is

> PROGRESS: ...After Effects successfully launched...

but that's all and it stops executing without any error. No movie is rendered. (No counting frames are displayed)

When I execute the exact same php file from the command line interface  (Terminal) like:

```
 $ php batchrender.php
```

All works perfect and it starts to render the movie.

in the httpd file the user for apache2 is defined as "abc" and group is "staff" the terminal is also started with user "abc"

Comment: could be a memory issue, and apache killing the process. Remember that via the web apache launches a process that has PHP in it. via command line there is no apache process.

Comment: There are separate `php.ini` files for php lounched by browser (with apache) and for `cli` (terminal - without apache) maybe you have different values for `max_execution_time` or `memory_limit` - usual `php.ini` for `cli` has more memory and it could run for longer period of time.

Comment: Maybe somebody has also another idea, how I could start this aerender remotly. It's basically all about starting the aerender unix command from a remote location. (I enter some data in a web application (php/mysql) and from there I'd like to run the render engine, which is at another location, not the same network, so it should be accessable via internet)